# A/B Testing: Is it necessary to test old versions every now and then?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, ab-test

Recently I was talking to a coworker about A/B Testing -- we run a variety of A/B tests on our website and the thought of doing a "back test" was mentioned where we essentially restore an old design we threw away because after a variety of tests has proven to be worse to test again.

The reasoning mentioned was that as time goes on your business model or your target demographic might change and even though their experience back then may have been worse, it is not an "apples to apples" comparison to say that the old design would perform poorly now. There is also this sense of testing if other parts of the business may have attributed to the target goal and seeing if the lift we are seeing in the new designs are actually because of the new design or because of the other parts of the business.

**how common practice is it in A/B Testing to test old designs or old tests to verify things are still going well?**

Comment: There's no A/B Testing police. You can run them on anything you want, from any time period, and if anything it would be useful to confirm your current design outperforms your old design. It's not uncommon, mainly due to statistical error (and lack of Bonferonni's correction), to iterate a design which suddenly becomes worse. And this doesn't even take into account your changing userbase and its demands

Comment: @AlexR. that helps a lot and thanks for mentioning Bonferonni's correction (learned something new). I guess I'm curious as to how necessary this is in the process given that if we are constantly iterating over old designs through A/B Tests that we would have to ask ourselves, "After X number of A/B tests each of which increased our specific goal (and after each A/B test we roll the winner out to the control), we should verify that the old design Y number of A/B tests ago actually performs worse than what we have now. Feel free to submit your comment as an answer btw.